# 24 bit-address in hex

Tags: memory, hex, bit, memory-address

How many hex digits does a 24-bit memory address have?

Comment: How many bits are in a hex digit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One hex digit corresponds to 4 binary digits(bits)

for 24 bits, there are 3 bytes(8bits) which makes 6 hex digits.

Answer (score 5):

- 8 bits = 1 byte
- 24 bits = 3 bytes
- 1 byte = 2 hex characters
- 2 bytes = 4 hex characters
- 3 bytes = 6 hex characters

Answer (score 2):

Each hex digit handles four bits, so a 24-bit address requires six hex digits. You can see the relationship between hex and binary here:

```
Hex  Binary       Hex  Binary
---  ------       ---  ------
 0    0000         8    1000
 1    0001         9    1001
 2    0010         A    1010
 3    0011         B    1011
 4    0100         C    1100
 5    0101         D    1101
 6    0110         E    1110
 7    0111         F    1111
```

Answer (score 2):

every hex is 4 bits,
every number in base 16, is 2^4 
hence 4 digits in base 2